# in Lisp how to write a number into a file in non-scientific notation?

Tags: floating-point, lisp, common-lisp, number-formatting

I'm trying to write into a text file some trigonometric results, and they come in weird format like:

```
(-0.5000000000000003d0 6.12323399573677d-17 -0.8660254037844385d0)
```

while I need

```
(0.500 0.000 -0.866)
```

How do I format or round number to 3 or 4 decimals and without scientific d0 at the end of number? Thanks.

```
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist vertexcount)
      (list (* (cos currentlat) (cos currentlon))
            (* (cos currentlat) (sin currentlon))
            (sin currentlat)))

(dotimes (nn vertexcount)
  (setq line  (elt sphereverticeslist nn))
  (setq line (write-to-string line))
  (write-line line file)
  (dolist (line '( "," ))
    (write-line line file)))
```

Expecting

```
(-0.500 0.000 -0.866)
```

Actual Result:

```
 (-0.5000000000000003d0 6.12323399573677d-17 -0.8660254037844385d0)
```

Comment: Use `FORMAT` with `%,3f` format to print floats with 3 decimal places.

Comment: Why does it matter? When you read it back in from the file you'll get the original value. Why do you want to throw away details?

Comment: `-0.5000000000000003d0` will not be changed into `0.500` by any formatting, as the change of sign makes it a very different number. Just a typo or is something else wrong?

Comment: The absence of the `d` also makes it a different *type*; not a `double-float`, which can potentially break whatever reads the numbers back if it then does stuff that assumes the numbers are that  specific type.

Comment: Thanks for answers, yes -0.5 and 0.5 is a typo. Tried to fix it like this: (setq line (format nil "~,3f" (elt (elt sphereverticeslist nn) tothree))))       (setq line (write-to-string line))
      (write-line line file) but this gives me "0.500" with double quotes in file, while I need doublequoteless 0.500. Maybe removing first and last character from string will help? Thanks.